# Error: Service instance has no attribute 'SvcDoRun'

Tags: python, windows, winapi, service, pywin32

Using python 2.7 on windows 7 64 bit machine. I had followed the link http://essiene.blogspot.in/2005/04/python-windows-services.html But getting error when seen in Events Viewer Windows Logs as 
**Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\win32serviceutil.py", line 835, in SvcRun self.SvcDoRun() AttributeError: Myservice instance has no attribute 'SvcDoRun'**.

Code snippet is as:

```
import win32service
import win32serviceutil
import win32api
import win32con
class Myservice(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "Myservice"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Myservice"

def __init__(self,args):
    win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
    self.isAlive = True

def SvcDoRun(self):
    while self.isAlive:
        if len(List)!=0:
            for i in range(0,len(List)):
                t = ThreadClass(NameList[i],name)
                t.start()

def SvcStop(self):
    import servicemanager

    self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
    self.isAlive = False

def ctrlHandler(ctrlType):
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ctrlHandler, True)
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(Myservice)
```

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled over the same problem. You need to indent the function definitions, otherwise they don't belong to the MyService class. So your code must look like this:

```
import win32service
import win32serviceutil
import win32api
import win32con
class Myservice(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "Myservice"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Myservice"

    def __init__(self,args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.isAlive = True

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        while self.isAlive:
            if len(List)!=0:
                for i in range(0,len(List)):
                    t = ThreadClass(NameList[i],name)
                    t.start()

    def SvcStop(self):
        import servicemanager

        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        self.isAlive = False

    def ctrlHandler(ctrlType):
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ctrlHandler, True)
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(Myservice)
```